# How do I evaluate string lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, int

I'm trying to make a script that evaluates a word to see whether or not its parts add up to 23 in any way (all four operations).

I've gotten it down to creating a string list of possible equations:

```
answerList = [12+15+12,12+15-12,12+15/12,...]
```

The problem I'm now getting is that I cannot get them back out of the lists in integer format to see whether or not they actually equal 23/32.

Comment: Are you trying to index into a list? `answerList[index]` will do that. I can't say much more without knowing what a word is and how it is evaluated

Comment: a word is any word whatsoever. I input a word, it breaks it down into its pieces, and then is supposed to evaluate them. So, for instance, I'd type in 'lol', it'd place it into a list of ['l', 'o', 'l'], then it would match that against an alphabet to number list for its number equivalent, then put that into a different list giving me ['12', '15', '12']. I'd take that list, use a nested for list to add operations, and get a third list filled with the iterations of operations (like ++, +-, +/, +*, --,...). I just didn't have a way of taking them out of that list. Eval() worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the eval() function

```
>>> eval("12+15+12")
39
>>> eval("12+15/12")
13
```

Then, you can just loop through the list, calling eval on each while doing something with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data like your example it will automatically convert them to integer anyway
e.g. :

```
>>> answerList = [12+15+12,12+15-12,12+15/12, ...]
>>> answerList
[39, 15, 13, ...]
```

However, if you want to store it and print it out which equation has result 23, your need to store them as a string then use eval to convert them to int to check that it equal to 23 or not then print out the equation.

```
answerList = ['12+15+12','12+15-12','12+15/12']
for equation in answerList :
  if eval(equation) == 23 :
    print equation
```

Comment: You know, I thought it'd do that too, but it actually wasn't auto converting them. I had seen that type of behavior before, so I was fairly certain I wouldn't run into any problems doing it that way. Apparently I must of done something weird, but at least I got the job done eventually. Haha